# Firebase CLI download restriction

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

I have a firebase database linked to an iOS app on which users have to be logged-in to read data from a specific node

So I edited my security rules :

```
"data": {
".read": "auth != null"
}
```

Nevertheless I would like to prevent users to download the whole node data via firebase CLI

I looked at the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth but I am not sure I have properly understood what to do.

**How can I disable data download over Firebase CLI ? Or is there a way to restrict downloading data by a specific user.uid or a given ip ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard users (i.e. users declared in the Authentication module) cannot use their credentials to authenticate with the CLI, only "admin" users declared through the "Users and permissions" page can do so.

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=[ProjectName]

You reach this page by clicking on the gear icon located in the upper left corner of the Firebase console, on the right of the "Project Overview" title

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: @scienst Note that it is the same with the Firebase console, from which you can read the full database.